How to bypass persistent auto-suggestions in mobile app text fields during automation?
I'm facing an issue with my mobile automation script where auto-suggestions in text fields interfere with my test scenario. Specifically, I'm automating a login flow where I need to input an email address, but the auto-suggestion overlay keeps reappearing after I clear the field or navigate away from it.
I've tried various approaches, such as tapping outside the field, using back buttons, and even directly setting the field value, but none seem to reliably bypass the auto-suggestion. It reappears whenever I interact with the field again, causing my tests to fail.
Is there a recommended strategy or workaround to handle persistent auto-suggestions in mobile app automation? How can I ensure that my automation script can input text into fields without being interrupted by auto-suggestions?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Appium Inspector

have you tried hiding the keyboard?  hiding the keyboard stops auto suggestion

Yes, I've attempted that as well. It appears to only hide the keyboard. However, when I click on the email field again, the auto-suggestion field pops up in the foreground, preventing me from clicking on the email field in the background, as shown in the screenshot.
